# How do I proc out with tilde expansion AND $PATH searching in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, process, elm

I'm trying to run the elm-reactor project, which is written in Haskell. It fails because it's trying to proc out to the `elm` command like this:

```
createProcess (proc "elm" $ args fileName)
```

My elm executable is sitting in ~/.cabal/bin, which is in my PATH.

The `System.Process.proc` command searches the $PATH for its command argument, but it doesn't do tilde (~) expansion, so it doesn't find elm.

`System.Process.shell` has the opposite problem.  It does tilde expansion, but it doesn't search the $PATH, apparently.

From the source of the System.Process command, it looks like most everything rests on a foreign ccall to "runInteractiveProcess", which I assume is doing whatever $PATH searching is being done.  I don't know where the source for runInteractiveProcess would be, and my C is about 15 years worth of rusty.

I can work around this issue by

a) adding the fully-expanded cabal/bin path to my PATH or

b) symlinking an `elm` from the working directory to its location in cabal/bin.

However, I'd like to offer a suggested fix to the elm project, to save future adopters the trouble I've gone through.  Is there a `System.Process` call that they should be making here that I haven't tried?  Or is there a different method they should be using? I suppose at worst they could `getEnv` for the PATH and HOME, and implement their own file search using that before calling proc - but that breaks cross-platform compatibility.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: What kind of system are you running on (if Linux, what flavor?) and what is `/bin/sh` - is it linked to `/bin/bash` or is it the [Almquist shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell)?

Comment: According to [bug-bash](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-08/msg00007.html) the bash shell is breaking the POSIX standard by expanding ~ in the PATH list. Coherently, instead, the POSIX execvp (which is called by Haskell) does __not__ expand it. I would recommend to do a) expand ~ in the PATH.

Comment: @user5402 I'm using Debian GNU/Linux with /bin/sh pointing to Almquist.  chi I guess that indicates that Almquist is more compliant with POSIX standard.  I'm going to follow user5402's suggestion to use $HOME in my PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `shell` instead of `proc`, i.e.:

```
createProcess (shell "elm")
```

This should invoke `elm` via a shell, which hopefully will interpret tildes in `$PATH` as desired.

Update: Here is the experiment I performed to test what `shell` does...

1. Compile the following program (I called it `run-foofoo`):

   import System.Process

   main = do
     (*,*,_,h) <- createProcess $ shell "foofoo"
     ec <- waitForProcess h
     print ec
2. Create a new directory `~/new-bin` and place the following perl script there as the file `foofoo`:

   #!/usr/bin/perl

   print "Got here and PATH is $ENV{PATH}\n";
3. Run: `chmod a+rx ~/new-bin/foofoo`

Test with:

```
PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ./run-foofoo                  # should fail
PATH="$HOME/new-bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ./run-foofoo    # should succeed
PATH="~/new-bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ./run-foofoo        # ???
```

On my OSX system, the third test reports:

```
Got here and PATH is ~/new-bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin
ExitSuccess
```

Comment: I did try shell.  As I mentioned above, "System.Process.shell has the opposite problem. It does tilde expansion, but it doesn't search the $PATH, apparently."  So `createProcess (shell "~/.cabal/bin/elm")` succeeds but `createProcess (shell "elm")` fails.

Comment: I get:

    /bin/sh: 1: foofoo: not found
    ExitFailure 127

Thanks for the suggestion of using $HOME in my path instead of tilde. From chi's comment above, it looks like that is more POSIX compliant.